# SQL - Getting TOP value per attribute in results set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where the following query:

```
SELECT
Purchasing.Supplier,
PurchasingParts.Part,
PurchasingParts.Description,
PurchasingParts.CostPerUnit,
PurchasingParts.PurchaseOrderNum,
PurchasingParts.ItemNum
FROM PurchasingParts
INNER JOIN Purchasing ON PurchasingParts.PurchaseOrderNum = Purchasing.PurchaseOrderNum
WHERE Supplier = 'Sup1'
ORDER BY PurchasingParts.PurchaseOrderNum DESC
```

Returns the following results:

```
Supplier    Part    Description CostPerUnit PurchaseOrderNum    ItemNum
Sup1        cm-14b  NULL        9.99        37163               1
Sup1        cm-13   jkljlkjlk   9.99        37160               1
Sup1        cm-13   jkljlkjlk   NULL        37158               1
```

However, I would then like to filter that set of results, so that only the most recent order (i.e. with the Highest PurchaseOrderNum) PER PART (Acting just on the Part attribute) is shown. So in this case, the final results would be:

```
Supplier    Part    Description CostPerUnit PurchaseOrderNum    ItemNum
Sup1        cm-14b  NULL        9.99        37163               1
Sup1        cm-13   jkljlkjlk   9.99        37160               1
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Within `PurchasingParts` table, do you have an id column or perhaps the date of the order?

Comment: The id for the PurchasingParts table is a composite key of PurchaseOrderNum & ItemNum

Comment: What about date of order? Do you have that field there?

Comment: No, because the higher the purchase order number (it auto-increments), the more recent the order date.

Comment: If the order number auto-increments with each record (the SQL server increments it, right?) what is the meaning of `ItemNum`? I.e. can we have multiple `ItemNum`s for the same order? Is `ItemNum` just the id for the `Part`?

Comment: No, in my implementation you can't. Plus it's a composite primary key, so if you tried to add the following P0001 - 1 (2nd num being the item num) then you'd get a primary key violation. Item num is simply an integer as to the individual item on the purchase order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
    SELECT
        Purchasing.Supplier,
        PurchasingParts.Part,
        PurchasingParts.Description,
        PurchasingParts.CostPerUnit,
        PurchasingParts.PurchaseOrderNum,
        PurchasingParts.ItemNum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PurchasingParts.Part ORDER BY PurchasingParts.PurchaseOrderNum DESC) as rnk
    FROM PurchasingParts
    INNER JOIN Purchasing ON PurchasingParts.PurchaseOrderNum = Purchasing.PurchaseOrderNum
    WHERE Supplier = 'Sup1'
    ) t
WHERE t.rnk = 1
ORDER BY t.PurchaseOrderNum DESC
```

Comment: That works but only if I take out the ORDER BY line: "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified." I'm Using SQL Server 2014